# How Do I Dynamically Add an Attribute to a Lit Element?

Tags: javascript, lit

I want to dynamically add an attribute to a Lit anchor element but I can't figure out how to do it. Specifically I want to add the download attribute.

**Simple Attribute**

This works:

```
return html`<a ?disabled=${this.disabled} download>Click here</a>`
```

This does not:

```
const downloadAttribute = this.download ? "download" : "";
return html`<a ?disabled=${this.disabled} ${downloadAttribute}>Click here</a>`
```

**Attribute With Value**

This works:

```
return html`<a ?disabled=${this.disabled} download=${fileName}>Click here</a>`
```

This does not:

```
const downloadAttribute = this.download ? `download=${filename}` : "";
return html`<a ?disabled=${this.disabled} ${downloadAttribute}>Click here</a>`
```

Any ideas as to how to get Lit to read downloadAttribute as an attribute and not as a string that it ignores?

Comment: Did you try `?download=${this.download}`, assuming `this.download` is Boolean? I have no experience with Lit, just basing it on the pattern of `disabled`...

Comment: Yes you are correct that does work. I have added a second scenario where the filename may or may not be included.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be like:

```html
import { ifDefined } from 'lit/directives/if-defined.js';
return html`<a ?disabled=${this.disabled} download=${ifDefined(fileName)}>Click here</a>`
```

As per documentation:
https://lit.dev/docs/api/directives/#ifDefined

Answer (score 0):

For boolean attributes, you can add a `?` in front of the attribute within the template.

```js
return html`
  <a ?disabled=${this.disabled} ?download=${this.download}>
    Click here
  </a>`;
```

For conditionally adding an attribute, use the [`ifDefined`](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#ifdefined) directive.

```js
import {ifDefined} from 'lit/directives/if-defined.js';


return html`
  <a
    ?disabled=${this.disabled}
    download=${ifDefined(this.download ? filename : undefined)}
  >Click here</a>`;
```